# Will Ubuntu 12.04 work with Intel-based 10 Gigabit adapters?

Tags: networking, server, drivers, hardware

I'm trying to see if ubuntu 12.04 LTS can handle/support 10gb connections.

Comment: What's the 10G card model?

Comment: @izx AOC-STGN-i2S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Ubuntu 12.04 will work just fine and includes built-in support for Intel 10 GbE controllers, which are used by your [Supermicro AOC-STGN-i2S 10 Gigabit Ethernet PCI-E card](ftp://ftp.supermicro.com/CDR.../datasheet-AOC-STGN-i2S.pdf).

Open-source drivers are in fact included with the Linux kernel, as `ixgbe*` modules, so you should never have to install drivers separately.